# Where did the weapons on the Millennium Falcon come from?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens*, Han and Chewie recover the Millennium Falcon and fly to Takodana with Finn and Rey. Before going to Maz's castle, however, Han hands out blasters to everyone.

Given that the *Falcon* had not been in Han's possession for some time, why were the weapons there? I believe that while the *Falcon* languished on Jakku, it was used for spare parts. At the very least, wouldn't Unkar Plutt have emptied the weapons locker and used them for his own purposes?

Comment: They were previously aboard Han's larger ship, I don't think it's inconceivable that they moved some weapons onto it.

Comment: "I believe that while the Falcon languished on Jakku, it was used for  spare parts." Do you have any basis for that?

Comment: @Tim Only Rey saying "That's garbage!" I'm assuming that if it's been junked, like cars on our planet, then it's used for spare parts. Partly, I made that statement to see if someone could prove otherwise (i.e., from the novelization).

Comment: "That's garbage" doesn't mean its been junked.  I've walked past many a functioning car and thought "What a piece of junk." But somehow the car had an up-to-date warrant and registration.

Comment: But as for the weapons - Han knew all the hiding places, probably had some stashed there that the other owners never found.

Answer (score 5):

As I see it there are three possible ways the weapons were on the ship.

1. They were on there from when Han last had it.

   - Hidden in some secret compartment
   - Not taken off because reasons (Part of the ship, not worth it, didn't see them etc.)
2. Han and Chewie moved them onto the Falcon from their larger ship before the whole Rathtar bit.
3. The group took some weapons with them when they were escaping the Rathtar (though [re-watching the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlWc_IBBfGY) this doesn't seem to be the case.

On a side note, I don't think the Falcon was being used for spare parts. After all, why would Unkar Plutt have modified it if he intended on stripping it down?

Comment: Don't you mean to say, "Why would Unkar Plutt have kept it in barely flying condition if he was using it for spare parts?"

Comment: @scott It seemed perfectly fine flying to my after no modifications. The only "bad" change it had was the compressor but it was fine under normal flying with that and Unkar Plutt must have thought it was a good modification seeing as Rey argued against it.

Answer (score 1):

Han Solo is a smuggler and his ship is a smuggling ship that is also highly modifiable. I believe he had weapons that shouldn't be there because he has hidden compartments that held contraband or illegal weaponry, and because they are hidden, Unkar Plutt or other previous owners did not know about them. It is not at all farfetched considering what I said in the first sentence.

Comment: The thing is, if I recall the scene, the place where Han grabbed the blasters did not look to be in some hidden, inaccessible, contraband location.

Comment: You said inaccessible. Hidden compartments are usually pretty accessible, but really well hidden. Anyway, I should check the scene again.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novelization)), they were in a "storage unit" on board the Falcon. Based on the description, it seems likely that these are Han's guns and that the locker was ignored by Plutt because of the seeming mess and low value of items in it (unless you had a good rummage, obviously).

> Still on board, Han popped a storage unit and began rummaging through the contents. From among the jumble he withdrew one used blaster after another, placing them carefully to one side. He was still at it when Finn came up behind him.

This aligns with the [film script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) which refers to them as "old BLASTERS".

> INT. MILLENNIUM FALCON - LOUNGE AREA - DAY
>
> From BLACKNESS: a storage unit opens. Han rummages, retrieving old BLASTERS. Finn arrives behind him, concerned.